# What is the best way to claim my ETHW (POW) forked coins after the merge?

Tags: the-merge

What is an easy way to claim my ETHW post merge forked coins? Is there a good RPC to connect to?

Comment: If they are in a wallet that is under your control you have to wait until a wallet that supports it appears, or you could run a copy of their forked version of geth. In their github there was an RPC, but most of them were down.

Answer (score 1):

You can deposit ETH onto CEX that have announced they will support the PoW work. These CEX most certainly will give users their equivalent ETHW after the merge. If you're unwilling to deposit ETH onto CEX, you can hold ETH in a non-custodial ETH wallet and will guarantee your address will receive ETHW on the new PoW fork. Accessing a non-custodial wallet is also likely faster for accessing your ETHW after the merge than accessing accounts on CEX.